# Bootstraping weighted functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to use `Bootstrap.jl` functions to obtain the Standard Error (SE) of a weighted function (e.g. a weighted median).

See below the `Bootstrap.bootstrap` code to obtain the SE of an unweighted median.

```
using StatsBase, DataFrames, Bootstrap

v = collect(1:1:20)

bootstrap(median, v, BasicSampling(100))
```

I would now need to pass a second argument to `median` above to obtain the SE of the weighted `median`. Outside of the `bootstrap` function, this looks like:

```
w = collect(0.1:0.1:2)
median(v, Weights(w))
```

How can I pass a second argument to the `median` function inside `bootstrap` to include the weights? Notice that the bootstrap resampling should be applied to both vectors, drawing the same indices for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `DataFrame` containing both vectors to the second argument of `bootstrap`. Then write an anonymous function to use each of the columns within `median`. E.g.

```
df = DataFrame(v = collect(1:1:20),
          w = collect(0.1:0.1:2))

bootstrap(d -> median(d[!,:v], Weights(d[!,:w])), df, BasicSampling(100))
```

Comment: Can't you just close over the weights without the data frame? `v -> median(v, Weights(w))`.

Comment: @phipsgabler If you use `bootstrap(v -> median(v, Weights(w)), v, BasicSampling(10000))` you'll see that the SE and bias are very different (and much larger). I believe this is because the function is resampling `v` but keeping the vector `w` intact. This means that resampled cases in `v` are then using weights which don't correspond to the observation. Passing a `DataFrame` keeps each observation in `v` matched to their correct weight.